# Chart.js automatic scaling

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I've been testing out chart.js for maybe including it in a project. I just have one smallish issue with it. It doesn't scale some datasets properly. I found somewhat similar questions here in SO, but nothing really that would solve my issue.

So this is what my chart looks like with some datasets:
[image]

For some reason, the max values (2.2) look ugly as hell. The reason is, that the dataset has a set of three duplicate values in this case (2.2, 2.2, 2.2). I would like there to be some room on top of this series, so that it would look a bit more reasonable.

How do you properly add "padding" on top the the series line? I would like a solution where I could rely on chart.js to find out the max value, and then maybe update that with some padding on the scale(like x + 10). Issue is, that I cant just hard code the min max values, because I can have over 200 different values that can be selected, and they can vary A LOT in scale.

Here is how I render the chart for now:

```
    return new Chart(context, {
    type: 'line',
    data: { 
        labels: labels.data,
        datasets: dataSets
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        scales: {
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero: false
            },
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: false
                },
                id: 'A',
                type: 'linear',
                position: 'left',
            }, {
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: false
                },
                display: displayBAxis,
                id: 'B',
                type: 'linear',
                position: 'right',
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you show me your dataSets? I don't need everything but I just need to see how you reference it all. After that I can give you your solution.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the cleanest way but you can play with it as you see fit.

In short, you need to create a function that finds the max value out of all your dataSets arrays and in yAxes.ticks set max to that functions return value.

More details below

**Referencing here first:**

```
data:{
    labels: labels.data,
    datasets: dataSets //talking about this first
}
```

Create a function that will go through these arrays and get the max of all arrays. I did it using this but you can do it better I'm sure:

```
function getMax(){
    var max = 0;
    dataSets.forEach(function(x, i){        
        max = Math.max(max, Math.max.apply(null, x.data));
    });

    return max + 2;
}
```

Then in your `return` in yAxes you should be able to have:

```
ticks: {
    beginAtZero: false,
    max: getMax()
},
```

Comment: Yeah I figured something like this, problem is that adding for example +2 is not a good fit in every series, because the series can be for example [0.1, 0.2, 0.5] or [1500, 1800, 3500, 3600]. But I kind of did something similar to what you suggested but just had to add a bunch of conditions to check that what is the range for the current series (or seriesis) and find the max and min values from those. But thanks for the idea anyway

Comment: As stated it wasn't the cleanest. You could figure out the tick spacing and make it equal to that so it looks more "out of the box". But if the answer suffices your needs please accept it or close the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the min and max of your dataset, then add/subtract a percentage of the difference (range).

For example, say you use 1% of the range.

[0.1, 0.2, 0.5] gives (1%)x(0.5-0.1)=0.004, so [min,max]=[0.096,0.504].

[1500, 1800, 3500, 3600] gives (1%)x(3600-1500)=21, so [min,max]=[1479,3621].